# Fetching data, conditional table codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

My login system works properly, it opens a different page if the username & password written correspond to a ADMIN or a simple user.

All users are stored in the table "usuarios".

> "usuarios" includes:(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date).

When i enter the system as an ADMIN the program must show a table with all the "simple" users stored in the table "usuarios".

I need something like this:
[image]

I do not know how to make the query :/.

This is my code:

My view file ("user_view"):

```
<div id="body">     
    <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
        <thead>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php

if ($records) { echo "<tr> <td>".$records['id']."</td> <td>".$records['username']."</td> <td>".$records['name']."</td> <td>".$records['lastname']."</td> <td>".$records['password']."</td> <td>".$records['type']."</td> <td>".$records['status']."</td> <td>".$records['date']."</td> </tr>"; }
?>

</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller file:

```
public function info_usuarios(){

    $data['records']=$this->m_login->getINFOUSER();
    $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
    print_r($data);
}
```

The model function (this function only shows the data of the user that logged in)

```
public function getINFOUSER(){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Comment: if you want to show all the users you shouldn't use the session in in your where clause, because it will always return a unique row from your database. Instead you can use your status field.

Comment: @heliosk But mate, i do not get it. How can i show all "user" rows (NOT ADMIN rows)?

Comment: @pradeep Take a look pal :S

Comment: which column do you use to declare if a user is an admin or a simple user?

Comment: @heliosk "type"=0 is an ADMIN "type"= 1 simpe user

Comment: @heliosk i thought something like this:
https://i.gyazo.com/9a42c4f3d609208fe26c799096c3683e.png

Comment: just change your parameters: get_where('usuarios', array('type' => 1), that will do it.

Comment: @heliosk what about the view file mate? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple, you do a simple query to find all users of `type = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE type=1;
```

That's all.

You can use CodeIgniter way of coding.

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('type =' => 1))->result();
```

Comment: Not working properly dude:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327024/issue-trying-to-fetch-data-codeigniter